# Mysql says user max connections exceeded

Tags: php, mysqli, statements

I have a CMS that is failing when more than one person is logged in. I think the problem may be that I'm not closing databases properly. Here is the basic setup:

I have a master class called Mysql. The __construct() method looks something like this:

```
class Mysql {

    protected $conn;

    function __construct() {

        if(!$this->conn) $this->conn = New mysqli(SITE_HOSTNAME, SITE_USERNAME, SITE_PASSWORD, SITE_DATABASE);

}
```

All of my classes are descendants of this class, and so whenever they are instantiated, they get their own connection.

I'm using prepared statements to protect against sql injection. A sample method might look like this:

```
function foo($blog = 0) {

    $query = "SELECT catid, catname
              FROM category
              WHERE blog = ?
              ORDER BY catname ASC";

    $result = array();
    if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $blog);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($catid, $catname);
        while($stmt->fetch()) $result[$catid] = stripslashes($catname);
        $stmt->close();
        return $result;
    }

}
```

The Mysql __destruct() method looks like this:

```
function __destruct() {
    if($this->conn) $this->conn->close();
}
```

Is my problem that I am not closing my connections properly, or that I do not have enough active connections?

My provider says that I have 30 simultaneous connections available. Not enough?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using persistent connection ?

Comment: Why are all of your classes descendants of your database layer? You should be either passing it to them with dependency injection, or into each method that needs to actually use a database connection. You don't need to give every class instance its own connection.

Comment: How would you like I answer you "Is 30 simultaneous connections available enought?". It totally depends on your traffic !

Comment: Are you creating more than 30 instances per request that inherit from `Mysql` class?

Comment: Unless you have persistent connections and more than 30 (say) Apache children, each holding open its own connection, or you're actually opening more than 30 connections in a single script, then the above code should NOT run out of connection capacity.

Comment: @Abhik Not using persistent connections.

Comment: I guess the question then, should I be using PDO if a single method is going to call other methods?

Comment: @crush I don't think so. But it's possible.

Comment: @crush However, I do have some scripts that do the following: creates a list of userids, then loops through each userid to get that user's info. The method creates a new object each time to call the fetchUser() method, but the variable is deleted and the __destruct() method is called each time. I'll have to check.

Comment: Are you saying you don't think 30 instances of classes that inherit Mysql somewhere in the chain are being created in a single request?

Comment: Also, I do agree that using `PDO` would be preferred here instead of recreating the wheel. You can then pass the single instance of `PDO` to your objects like I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Problem

> All of my classes are descendants of this class, and so whenever they
>   are instantiated, they get their own connection.

The problem with the way you are doing it is that every single instance of any class that inherits `Mysql` is opening a connection to the `Mysql` server that lives until the request is completed, or the variable destructed (unless you are killing these objects manually, that's at the end of the request). If you have 30 instance of classes like this, then you have maxed out your connections.

### Fixing The Problem

Your classes shouldn't all be inheriting this `Mysql` class that represents your interface to the database.

Instead, you should be passing a single instance of this `Mysql` class where it's needed.

There are two ways this could be done effectively:

### Dependency Injection

```
class SomeClass {
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(Mysql &$db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function functionThatNeedsDatabase() {
        $this->db->doSomethingWithTheDatabase();
    }
}

$db = new Mysql(); //A single instance of Mysql class has been created.
$someClass = new SomeClass($db);
$someClass->functionThatNeedsDatabase();
```

### Pass to Method When Needed

```
class SomeClass {
    public function functionThatNeedsDatabase(Mysql &$db) {
        $db->doSomethingWithTheDatabase();
    }
}

$db = new Mysql(); //A single instance
$someClass = new SomeClass();
$someClass->functionThatNeedsDatabase($db);
```

Comment: Thanks to Brent and crush for the answers. I will work on this tonight and let you guys know how it's going.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is "All of my classes are descendants of this class, and so whenever they are instantiated, they get their own connection." In PHP connection are automatically closed when the script ends. You really only need 1 connection per user. You should create an instance of your DB class and pass that object into all the classes that need to use it (Dependency Injection pattern).

30 connections is not a whole lot, but that is sufficient for a lot of traffic. I would avoid using persistent connections. Read the documentation thoroughly on that, there are plenty of warnings.